# Node mailer fails sending email for just 1 recipient from the 50

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send email using node mailer. I have an array of 50 people in bcc list. The email successfully went out to 49 people on the list and just one id was rejected from the list with the following error. I verified the email id and its a valid email. Can someone suggest what I might be doing wrong here?

Format I set the data

```
finalMailObject = {
                                 from:"fromaddrs@exampleid.com",
                                 bcc:res,
                                 subject:req.emailSubject,
                                 html:req.html
                        };
```

Error I am facing

```
 rejected: [ 'failingemailaddress@examplesite.com' ],
  rejectedErrors:
   [ { Error: Recipient command failed: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (Mail_Engine\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:781:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionRCPT (Mail_Engine\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1592:24)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (Mail_Engine\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1559:30)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (Mail_Engine\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:940:20)
    at Immediate.setImmediate [as _onImmediate] (Mail_Engine\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:941:37)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
       code: 'EENVELOPE',
       response: '502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized',
       responseCode: 502,
       command: 'RCPT TO',
       recipient: 'failingemailaddress@examplesite.com' } ],
```